# SQL Converting sum of null values to 0

Tags: mysql, sql, null, sum

I have a query in SQL which sum values and add them as months to a date.

```
    SELECT
    FROM_UNIXTIME(S.created) as start_date, 
   (FROM_UNIXTIME(S.created) + INTERVAL (C.items_left + C.items_given) MONTH)
    AS end_date,
    FROM table1 S
    LEFT JOIN table2 C ON C.id = S.id;
```

The problem arises when some of these values to sum are null instead of 0 and I am not able to change the source of data.

```
(FROM_UNIXTIME(S.created) + INTERVAL (C.items_left + C.items_given) MONTH)
AS end_date,
```

is generating nulls because `(C.items_left + C.items_given)` is null.

So, the question is, how do I execute this sum so the result is 0 instead of null?

Comment: [coalesce](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) should help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `coalesce`

```
SELECT
    FROM_UNIXTIME(S.created) as start_date, 
   ( coalesce(FROM_UNIXTIME(S.created),0) + INTERVAL coalesce((coalesce(C.items_left,0) + coalesce(C.items_given,0)),0) MONTH)
    AS end_date,
    FROM table1 S
    LEFT JOIN table2 C ON C.id = S.id;
```

Comment: Anyway I just put it in the sum `coalesce(C.items_left + C.items_given)`, as it's the only source of null data.

Comment: @Belen you can it inner as well for both items_left and items_given

Comment: @Belen inner is safe otherwise if items_left null and items_given has value in that case null+val also make it null

Comment: @zaybul, agreed, I'm going with your query, it works perfect as it is. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use `COALESCE()`:

```
(FROM_UNIXTIME(S.created) + INTERVAL (COALESCE(C.items_left, 0) + COALESCE(C.items_given, 0)) MONTH)
```